# JPanel Wont Load Image

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, loading

So I can't really figure out why I can't load an image into this JPanel....The code is kinda long, but I have it commented, so it should be fairly simple to deduce whats going on. Can anybody help? I have tried removing the background color and that did not seem to do much at all (other than remove the background color)

## Edit

I managed to fix the error where the drawScene method was being called in the class that it wasn't added to, and now it will show that there is an error loading the image...I'm not entirely sure why though.  This is the image that I am using if anybody wants to try running the program for themselves. I have it added in my package right underneath my Window.java file.

---

[image]

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
///

///WINDOW CLASS BEGINS

///

public class Window extends JPanel{

    //Instance Variables
    Tools tool = new Tools();
    GameScreen game = new GameScreen();
    Scene scene = new Scene();

    //All other variable initialization things
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public Window(){
        //Sets the layout to the class
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //adding things to the class
        this.add(game,BorderLayout.CENTER);


        //Sets background Colors to the panels
        this.game.setBackground(Color.black);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Window window = new Window();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setJMenuBar(Tools.bar);
        frame.add(window);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){



    }

    ///

// TOOLBAR CLASS BEGINS

    ////

    public static class Tools extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        public static JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("file");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public Tools(){

            //Set layouts
            this.panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            //Add to the bar 
            this.bar.add(file,BorderLayout.WEST);


            //add things to the inside of the bar
            this.file.add(this.exit);
            this.panel.add(this.bar);

            //add panels
            this.add(panel);

            //action Commands

            this.exit.setActionCommand("exit");

            //add action Listeners
            this.exit.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getActionCommand() == "exit"){
                System.out.println("Closed");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }

    }

    /////

    //GAMESCREEN CLASS BEGINS

    ////
    public class GameScreen extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        //Instance Variables

        Scene scene = new Scene();


        //JPanel variables

        JPanel screen =  new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        public GameScreen(){

            //Sets the class layout


            //Adding panels
            this.add(screen);

            //Setting the color
            this.screen.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));

            //Adding things to the panels
            this.screen.add(scene);


        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            scene.drawScence(g, "Backgound.jepg", 0, 0, 600, 600);
        }

    }


    public class Scene extends JPanel{


        public Scene(){

        }

        public void drawScence(Graphics g,String location,int x,int y,int width,int height){
            try{
                 URL url = this.getClass().getResource(location);
                 Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
                 g.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Unable to load image.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `///WINDOW CLASS BEGINS`  It's about bloody time.  Oh wait, 8 more lines of white space..  There is never a need for more than one blank line of white space in source. 2) Never try to load resources in the `paintComponent` method (or any method it calls).

Comment: As near as I can tell `Scene` is never added to anything...

Comment: In the constructor for the GameScreen class it is added. @MadProgrammer

Comment: But that's not the instance you are calling in the `paintComponent` method of the `Window` class...

Comment: Yes, but you have two instances.  The one you call drawScreen on isn't the one you add.  EDIT:  MadProgrammer got there before me.

Comment: thanks guys, but if you check out my edits I have new errors unfortunately. @MadProgrammer

Comment: You are still reading the image in the painting method. It also might help if you spell "jpeg" correctly.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that I didn't even see that! Thank you so much @camickr